# What is the difference between Xamarin android project and Xamarin cross-platform project?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm really struggeling what project to open to create mobile apps.

Because I can choose in Visual studio for creating an android app, creating an IOS app and crossplatform app. So what would be the difference in those 3? Because if I select "android app" it will automatically use xamarin, but isn't xamarin for cross-platform apps?

I hope you guys can help me out with this one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four project templates you can use for Xamarin:

**1. Xamarin Android:** With this project template, you can write an Android application based on C#.
[image]
 **2. Xamarin iOS:** With this project template, you can write an iOS application based on C#. 
[image]
 **3. Xamarin Cross-Platform (Native):** With this project template, you can write an Android and an iOS application. (You have to create a view for each platform)

**4. Xamarin Cross-Platform (Forms):** If you need to write an application, only with basic functionality and you want to create only one view for all platforms, then "Xamarin Forms" is the best choice.
 [image]
[image]
But to clarify, if you create a project with the cross-platform project template (3.), then you get a Visual Studio solution with three projects. Two of these projects are an Android project (1.) and an iOS project (2.), for specific code, and additionally there is a third project that you can use for writing cross-platform code.

If you want to create a cross-platform application, you have to choose between a **"Shared Project"** and a **"Portable Class Library"**, for the cross-platform code. The biggest difference between shared and portable is the usage of specific code. In a **"Shared Project"**, you use compiler directives to get a specific platform code, like iOS. In a **"Portable Class Library"**, you don't use the compiler directives. You only have to select a project, like the iOS project as start project and it works.

For more information about the difference between a "Shared" and "Portable" project look at [this page](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/).

A example of a native **Cross-Platform** application with a **"Portable Class Library"**:
[image]

With Xamarin Cross-Platform, you can not only develop for Android and iOS, you can develop for Windows Phone as well.

Comment: Puh, that was such work and I hope it is all right. If someone finds an issue, he could make me glad, if he commented it.

Comment: Amazing... I'm so thaknfull for your long post ! Thanks my friend !

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin allows you to create cross platform apps, which means your app will be able to turn on android, IOS & Windows Phones.

If you create a Xamarin Android project, it will only run on android.

Check this website for more info : https://university.xamarin.com/

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why why would someone want to build and Android app with Xamarin instead of Android Studio? What is the purpose of it?